# recursion with super keyword in java

Tags: java, class, object, recursion, super

Consider the following code :

```
public class TestClass
{
  TestClass()
  {
      super(); 
      System.out.printf("yes it is called");

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        new TestClass();
  }

}
```

Now as anonymous object is created , it calls the constructor. Now with super , it agian calls it self and again the process repeats . This should create infinite recursion.But this is not what happens . Why ?

Comment: super() calls the no-args constructor of the super class. And the super class is implicitely Object if you don't specify one. So it calls the no args constructor of the object class.

Comment: `super()` calls the constructor of the object it inherits from, not itself.

Comment: why would you think `super` calls the self constructor?

Comment: (also, `super` is always called implicitly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` in your case just calls `new Object()` (all java classes inherit from the Object class), something that would happen anyway. No recursion here

Answer (score 3):

This is not recursion.  In a constructor, calling `super();` calls the superclass constructor, not itself.

If you were to say `this();` inside that constructor, then the compiler would catch "recursive constructor invocation" as a compiler error.

Comment: In your case, it calla the `Object` constructor.

Comment: @rgettman this TestClass is a superclass of itself and that constructor is no arg constructor . so super() calls no arg constructor of it's super class which is the same constructor as itself , so why not recursion ??

Comment: No, no class can be a superclass of itself.  And `new TestClass();` doesn't create an instance of an anonymous subclass of `TestClass`, it just creates an instance of `TestClass`.  Even if it did, then it would have its own implicit no-arg constructor that implicitly calls the `TestClass` no-arg constructor, whose explicit `super();` would call `Object`'s no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

super() is in reference to the superclass, you are calling `Object`'s constructor.

If you were to make this infinite recursion, you would use `this`

```
public class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass() {
        this(); //recursion!
    }

}
```

Of course, this is a compilation error.